# Element API - lightswitch option to exclude an entry from a feed

Tags: element, api

I'm trying to exclude an entry based on the state of a lightswitch field in the entry itself. If true, exclude the entry from the feed, if false include the entry.

Comment: Hi Alan. It would help us help you if you explained what you tried already.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who happens to land on this trying to solve your similar challenge:

Super simple - the criteria can accept a custom field value, so in my case, the criteria became

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'caseOfTheMonth',
    'type' => 'standard',
    'hideFromFeed' => false,
],
```

What was getting in the way, in my case, was that I was fighting the Element API response cache when I was trying all my options, so I completely missed the most simple solution. That's my takeaway - manage that cache when testing!